# turning off display using display power 0

Tags: raspbian, display

I am working on the raspberry pi3 wrote the following code under sudo nano ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart 00 12 **** /usr/bin/vgencmd display_power 0 I know in terminal display_power 0 turns off the hdmi and the monitor then just needs to be turned off manually. Am I entering this code correctly so the display turns off at a certain time in this case it is set for noon. Any comments or suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: What is the question, are you wanting to turn the HDMI off / on at certain times of the day?

Answer (score 1):

## Turn on / off via Cronjob

If you want to turn the hdmi off and on at certain times you can do it via crontab.

```
crontab -e
```

add these two lines down the bottom

```
#on at 6am off at 6pm
0 6 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/pi/hdmi_on.sh
0 18 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/pi/hdmi_off.sh
```

create two files and remember to `chmod +x` both files

## html_off.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

tvservice -o
```

## html_on.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo tvservice -p
sudo chvt 1
sudo chvt 7
```